# Confused about Vercel's default caching strategy for static files

Tags: http, next.js, cdn, cache-control, vercel

In [Vercal's official doc](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/caching#static-files-caching), it says that

> Static files are automatically cached at the edge after the first request. Note that no manual adjustments are necessary to make this work.
> ... By default, a Cache-Control header is returned containing public, max-age=0, must-revalidate to prevent clients (e.g. browsers) from caching the file locally.

So my understanding is that Vercel caches static assets on the CDN by default without needing me to set up anything. But in its section about [Cache-control header](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/headers#cache-control-header) it says

> The default value is cache-control: public, max-age=0, must-revalidate which instructs both the Edge Network and the browser not to cache.

This seems to contradict what it stated about the default caching for static files earlier. So my questions is, does Vercel actually cache static files by default? if so, where and how? With the default header being `cache-control: public, max-age=0, must-revalidate` , I can't seem to understand how it caches static files by default on the CDN.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: That header does allow caching (i.e. storing the file), it just requires revalidation every time. So the language in the second part ("...not to cache") is sloppy. This ambiguity is unfortunately common in discussions of caching.

Comment: even with the absence of `s-max-age` in `Cache-control` header, does the CDN still caches/stores assets? I thought it has to be present.

Comment: I think what you're missing here is that their edge network is not a generic proxy cache. It does not have to rely on the `Cache-Control` header, it can be controlled by their own settings (like caching static files for up to 31 days), user settings (like `headers`), etc. What they're saying is to use `s-maxage` for generic responses, but that they have special code in place to recognize, handle, and cache static files.